# Close program (not terminate it, just close it as I just pressed X) with Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

Any script to do this?

I know of taskkill /f, but I think that one kills the process at hand. I don't want to do that. It's a program that I can close, but its icon still remains in the notification area. It starts at start-up, but I wanna know if I can just close it.

Comment: That highly depends on the application. Some of my applications minimize to the tray when I use X to close and are there when I need them. Others terminate when I use X to close. It is an application thing, not Windows thing.

Comment: I already know this program will go to the tray instead of just closing. I just want to schedule the program to close (but not terminate the process, aka, I want it out of my screen and gone to the tray)

Comment: [How To Minimize Any App To System Tray On Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/minimize-app-to-system-tray-windows-10/)